# JQuery to update the HTML of a div without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` that is displaying the contents of an order. Currently this is how I am implementing adding items to this `div` using `JQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //if cookie exists, show the panel
    if($.cookie('order_cookie') != undefined){

    productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));

    $(".order-alert").show();

    for(var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++){
       console.log(productArray[i]);
       var obj = productArray[i];
       $(".order-alert").append("<p> StockCode: " + obj.stockCode + " Qty: " + obj.quantity + "</p>");
       console.log("Object code: " + obj.stockCode + " Qty: " + obj.quantity);

    }

    $('#order_counter').html(productArray.length);
    }
});
```

I have it working so that when the user adds an item to the order the counter increments without reloading the browser window.

```
    $('#order_counter').html(productArray.length);
```

I'm just wondering how I could implement the same thing with my `loop` to output the items in the order as the user adds them to the `array`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This script adds items to `array`, the `cookie` is also set in the script

```
var productArray = []; // Will hold order Items

$(".orderBtn").click(function(event){
        //Check to ensure quantity > 0
        if(quantity == 0){
            console.log("Quantity must be greater than 0")
        }else{//It is so continue
            //Show the order Box
            $(".order-alert").show();
            event.preventDefault();

            //Get reference to the product clicked
            var stockCode = $(this).closest('li').find('.stock_code').html();
            //Get reference to the quantity selected
            var quantity = $(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val();

            //Order Item (contains stockCode and Quantity) - Can add whatever data I like here
            var orderItem = {
            'stockCode' : stockCode,
            'quantity'  : quantity
            };

            //Check if cookie exists 
            if($.cookie('order_cookie') === undefined){
            console.log("Creating new cookie");
            //Add object to the Array
            productArray.push(orderItem);
            }else{//Already exists
            console.log("Updating the cookie")
            productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));
            //Check if the item already exists in the Cookie and update qty

            var found = false;

            for(var i =0; i < productArray.length; i++){
                 if(productArray[i].stockCode == stockCode){
                 console.log("OBJECT EXISTS")
                 var index = i;
                 found = true;
                }
                }
                //If it exists update the old quantity
                if(found){
                //update
                console.log("Match found at: "  + index);
                var oldQty = (productArray[index].quantity)
                var newQty = parseInt(quantity) + parseInt(oldQty);
                productArray[index].quantity = newQty;

                }else{// It doesn't exist so add new item to array
                productArray.push(orderItem);
                }
            }
        }

        //Update the Cookie
        $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });

        //Testing output of Cookie
        console.log($.cookie('order_cookie'));
        //Update the order tracker
        $('#order_counter').html(productArray.length);
    });
```

Comment: How are the items being added to the array? What is setting the cookie?

Comment: Somethink like : function addToMyOrder(obj) { 
$(.order-alert).append(... obj ); addToMyCookie(obj); } ?
If you want to use the loop you should reload all the order

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1) Create another field for the order to print them in which you update when a user adds something to their order.

2) Implement the move to front heuristic on your product array so that when a product is incremented it's moved to the front of the array and the products originally in front of it are pushed back one space. As an example if you start with

```
"orange" => 1
"pear"   => 1
```

and then the user adds a pear followed by an apple, the result would be:

```
"apple"  => 1
"pear"   => 2
"orange" => 1
```

Both have issues when the array gets massive, but if you won't be getting orders containing hundreds of unique products, it shouldn't be an issue. 
Regardless of which method you use, you can update the list presented to the user by just using [`$('.order-alert').prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)